# How can I change the values in one column of a df without changing the ones in other columns? (with Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been trying to change the values of all the columns of my df. What happens is that my df has different columns with the same values, but I want to change them in different ways depending on the column (for example, I want the 1 in column "SEXO" to be "Varón" and the 1 in column "NIVEL_EDUCATIVO" to be "Primario incompleto"). I've tried this:

```
renombrada.SEXO.loc[renombrada.SEXO == 1] = "Varón"
renombrada.SEXO.loc[renombrada.SEXO == 2] = "Mujer"
renombrada.NIVEL_EDUCATIVO.loc[renombrada.NIVEL_EDUCATIVO == 1] = "Primario incompleto"
renombrada.NIVEL_EDUCATIVO.loc[renombrada.NIVEL_EDUCATIVO == 2] = "Primario completo"
renombrada.NIVEL_EDUCATIVO.loc[renombrada.NIVEL_EDUCATIVO == 3] = "Secundario incompleto"
```

But what happens is that it replaces all the 1s in my df with "Varón". What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I just tested it and it works fine.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataframe, including your expected result and your current output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@garagnoth provides a nice solution. This is what you were trying to do, but working:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

renombrada = DataFrame({
    'SEXO': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'NIVEL_EDUCATIVO': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
})

renombrada.loc[renombrada.SEXO == 1, 'SEXO'] = "Varón"
renombrada.loc[renombrada.SEXO == 2, 'SEXO'] = "Mujer"
renombrada.loc[renombrada.NIVEL_EDUCATIVO == 1, 'NIVEL_EDUCATIVO'] = "Primario incompleto"
renombrada.loc[renombrada.NIVEL_EDUCATIVO == 2, 'NIVEL_EDUCATIVO'] = "Primario completo"
renombrada.loc[renombrada.NIVEL_EDUCATIVO == 3, 'NIVEL_EDUCATIVO'] = "Secundario incompleto"

print(renombrada)
```

You were missing the column selector in there.

Note the definition of `renombrada` in the answer - that's assuming your dataframe is structured similarly. In future questions, please include something similar as part of the code in your question, so people know what you're operating on.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to use `map` to change the value.

Consider the following sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
renombrada = pd.DataFrame({
  'SEXO': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
  'NIVEL_EDUCATIVO': [1, 1, 2, 3, 1]
})
```

Dataframe:

```
>>> renombrada
    SEXO    NIVEL_EDUCATIVO
0   1       1
1   2       1
2   1       2
3   2       3
4   1       1
```

Prepare map for SEXO:

```
ren_sexo = {
  1: "Varón",
  2: "Mujer"
}
```

Then, use that to change `SEXO` value as follow:

```
renombrada.SEXO = renombrada.SEXO.map(ren_sexo)
```

This will give us:

```
    SEXO    NIVEL_EDUCATIVO
0   Varón   1
1   Mujer   1
2   Varón   2
3   Mujer   3
4   Varón   1
```